# Using dplyr and mutate to create new columns based on groups and last n rows

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following data frame as an example:

```
match_id <- c("match_1", "match_1","match_1","match_2","match_2","match_2","match_3","match_3","match_3", "match_4","match_4","match_4")
player_id <- c("player_1", "player_2", "player_3", "player_1", "player_2", "player_3", "player_1", "player_2", "player_3","player_1", "player_2", "player_3")
venue <- c("venue A", "venue A", "venue A", "venue B", "venue B", "venue B", "venue C", "venue C", "venue C","venue C", "venue C", "venue C")
opponent <- c("opponent A", "opponent A", "opponent A", "opponent B", "opponent B", "opponent B", "opponent C", "opponent C", "opponent C","opponent C", "opponent C", "opponent C")
points <- c(5,10,15,1,2,3,5,7,9,11,2,6)

data <- data.frame(match_id, player_id, venue, opponent, points)
```

I am looking to create new columns that show the last n values in the points column, based on groupings.

My attempt for the first group, using 3 games as an example:

```
#group by player, give the last n games
library(dplyr)
data <- data %>%
  arrange(player_id,desc(match_id)) %>%
  mutate(last3_games = lag(points, n=3)) %>%
  mutate(last2_games = lag(points, n=2)) %>%
  mutate(last1_games = lag(points, n=1))
```

Which gives:

```
 head(data)
  match_id player_id   venue   opponent points last3_games last2_games last1_games
1  match_4  player_1 venue C opponent C     11    NA         NA          NA
2  match_3  player_1 venue C opponent C      6    NA         NA          11
3  match_2  player_1 venue B opponent B      1    NA         11          5
4  match_1  player_1 venue A opponent A      5    11         5           1
5  match_4  player_2 venue C opponent C      2     5         1           5
6  match_3  player_2 venue C opponent C      7     1         5           2
7   match_2  player_2 venue B opponent B     3     5         2           7
8   match_1  player_2 venue A opponent A     10    2         7           2
```

But I would like the values shown as the last 3 values of points for each player, like so:

```
   match_id player_id   venue   opponent points last3_games last2_games last1_games
1   match_4  player_1 venue C opponent C     11    1         6           11
2   match_3  player_1 venue C opponent C      6    5         1           6
3   match_2  player_1 venue B opponent B      1    NA        5           1
4   match_1  player_1 venue A opponent A      5    NA        NA          5
5   match_4  player_2 venue C opponent C      2    3         7           2
6   match_3  player_2 venue C opponent C      7    10        3           7
7   match_2  player_2 venue B opponent B      3    NA        10          3
8   match_1  player_2 venue A opponent A     10    NA        NA          10
```

I also then want to do the same by opponent and venue like so:

```
#by opponent
       match_id player_id   venue   opponent points last3_opponent last2_opponent last1_opponent
1  match_4  player_1 venue C opponent C     11             NA             5             11
2  match_3  player_1 venue C opponent C      5             NA             NA            5
3  match_2  player_1 venue B opponent B      1             NA             NA            1
4  match_1  player_1 venue A opponent A      5             NA             NA            5
5  match_4  player_2 venue C opponent C      2             NA             7             2
6  match_3  player_2 venue C opponent C      7             NA             NA            7
7  match_2  player_2 venue B opponent B      2             NA             NA            2
8  match_1  player_2 venue A opponent A     10             NA             NA            10
```

There are many `NA's` here but this is because I am only showing a small example.

My attempt was to group these again and mutate using lag but it doesn't give the required output:

```
data <- data %>%
  arrange(player_id,desc(match_id), opponent) %>%
  mutate(last3_opponent = lag(points, n=3)) %>%
  mutate(last2_opponent = lag(points, n=2)) %>%
  mutate(last1_opponent = lag(points, n=1))
```

The output grouped by opponent AND venue should look like this:

```
    #by opponent and venue
  match_id player_id   venue   opponent points last3_opp_ven last2_opp_ven last1_opp_ven
1  match_1  player_1 venue A opponent A      5            NA            NA            5
2  match_2  player_1 venue B opponent B      1            NA            NA            1
3  match_4  player_1 venue C opponent C     11            NA             5            11
4  match_3  player_1 venue C opponent C      5            NA            NA            5
5  match_1  player_2 venue A opponent A     10            NA            NA            10
6  match_2  player_2 venue B opponent B      2            NA            NA            2
7  match_4  player_2 venue C opponent C      2            NA            7             2
8  match_3  player_2 venue C opponent C      7            NA            NA            7
```

Ideally, I am looking for up to the last 10 games (last 10, last 9, last 8, etc.), and as there are many opponents and many vanues, the resulting data frame will have quite a few columns.

Is there an easier way?

I also want to add a column at the end of each which has all of the values combined, for each group, like so (using the first example of games):

```
   match_id player_id   venue   opponent points last3_combined
1   match_4  player_1 venue C opponent C     11    1,6,11        
2   match_3  player_1 venue C opponent C      6    5,1,6         
3   match_2  player_1 venue B opponent B      1    NA,5,1        
4   match_1  player_1 venue A opponent A      5    NA,NA,5        
5   match_4  player_2 venue C opponent C      2    3,7,2         
6   match_3  player_2 venue C opponent C      7    10,3,7       
7   match_2  player_2 venue B opponent B      3    NA,10,3       
8   match_1  player_2 venue A opponent A     10    NA,NA,10
```

**Update:**

Suppose I want to use another variable (in this case `game_x`, to group by, but this variable only has two values (1 and 0).

I tried the below:

```
match_id <- c("match_1", "match_1","match_1","match_2","match_2","match_2","match_3","match_3","match_3", "match_4","match_4","match_4")
player_id <- c("player_1", "player_2", "player_3", "player_1", "player_2", "player_3", "player_1", "player_2", "player_3","player_1", "player_2", "player_3")
venue <- c("venue A", "venue A", "venue A", "venue B", "venue B", "venue B", "venue C", "venue C", "venue C","venue C", "venue C", "venue C")
opponent <- c("opponent A", "opponent A", "opponent A", "opponent B", "opponent B", "opponent B", "opponent C", "opponent C", "opponent C","opponent C", "opponent C", "opponent C")
game_x <- c(1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0)
points <- c(5,10,15,1,2,3,5,7,9,11,2,6)

data <- data.frame(match_id, player_id, venue, opponent, game_x, points)

library(data.table)

setDT(data)

f <- function(x,n=3) lapply(n:1,function(i) x[i:(i+length(x)-1)])

data[
  order(player_id, game_x, -match_id),
  c("last3", "last2", "last1"):=f(points,3),
  by=.(player_id, game_x)][]
```

But it produces this:

```
    match_id player_id   venue   opponent game_x points last3 last2 last1
 1:  match_1  player_1 venue A opponent A      1      5    NA    NA     5
 2:  match_1  player_2 venue A opponent A      1     10    NA    NA    10
 3:  match_1  player_3 venue A opponent A      0     15    NA    NA    15
 4:  match_2  player_1 venue B opponent B      1      1    NA     5     1
 5:  match_2  player_2 venue B opponent B      0      2    NA    NA     2
 6:  match_2  player_3 venue B opponent B      1      3    NA    NA     3
 7:  match_3  player_1 venue C opponent C      1      5     5     1     5
 8:  match_3  player_2 venue C opponent C      0      7    NA     2     7
 9:  match_3  player_3 venue C opponent C      0      9    NA    15     9
10:  match_4  player_1 venue C opponent C      1     11     1     5    11
11:  match_4  player_2 venue C opponent C      0      2     2     7     2
12:  match_4  player_3 venue C opponent C      0      6    15     9     6
```

When it should look like this:

```
    match_id player_id   venue   opponent game_x points last3 last2 last1
 1:  match_4  player_1 venue C opponent C      1     11     1     5    11
 2:  match_3  player_1 venue C opponent C      1      5     5     1     5
 3:  match_2  player_1 venue B opponent B      1      1    NA     5     1
 4:  match_1  player_1 venue A opponent A      1      5    NA    NA     5
 5:  match_4  player_2 venue C opponent C      0      2    NA    NA    NA
 6:  match_3  player_2 venue C opponent C      0      7    10    NA    NA
 7:  match_2  player_2 venue B opponent B      0      2    NA    10    NA
 8:  match_1  player_2 venue A opponent A      1     10    NA    NA    10
 9:  match_4  player_3 venue C opponent C      0      6    NA    NA     3
10:  match_3  player_3 venue C opponent C      0      9    NA    3     NA
11:  match_2  player_3 venue B opponent B      1      3    NA    NA     3
12:  match_1  player_3 venue A opponent A      0     15    NA    NA    NA
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Update 2:**

I am attempting to skip the NA's where game_x = 0 (and replace all values where game_x = 0 with NA).

What appears to be happening now is that NA appears in the column for last3, last2, etc. even when game_x = 0. Usng the last 5 as an example:

```
match_id <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
player_id <- c("player_1", "player_1", "player_1", "player_1", "player_1")
venue <- c("venue A", "venue A", "venue B", "venue B", "venue B")
opponent <- c("opponent A", "opponent B", "opponent A", "opponent C", "opponent C")
game_x <- c(1,1,0,1,0)
points <- c(5,10,15,1,2)

data <- data.frame(match_id, player_id, venue, opponent, game_x, points)

library(data.table)

setDT(data)

f <- function(x,n=3,m=rep(TRUE,length(x))) {
  x[!m] <- NA
  lapply(n:1,function(i) x[i:(i+length(x)-1)])
}

data[
  order(-match_id),
  c("last5", "last4", "last3", "last2", "last1"):=f(points,5,game_x==1),
  by=.(player_id)][order(player_id,-match_id)][]

data[order(-match_id)]
```

Output:

```
   match_id player_id   venue   opponent game_x points last5 last4 last3 last2 last1
1:        5  player_1 venue B opponent C      0      2     5    10    NA     1    NA
2:        4  player_1 venue B opponent C      1      1    NA     5    10    NA     1
3:        3  player_1 venue B opponent A      0     15    NA    NA     5       10    NA
4:        2  player_1 venue A opponent B      1     10    NA    NA    NA     5    10
5:        1  player_1 venue A opponent A      1      5    NA    NA    NA    NA     5
```

Should look like:

```
   match_id player_id   venue   opponent game_x points last5 last4 last3 last2 last1
1:        5  player_1 venue B opponent C      0      2   NA   NA    NA     NA   NA
2:        4  player_1 venue B opponent C      1      1   NA   NA    5    10     1
3:        3  player_1 venue B opponent A      0     15   NA   NA    NA    NA    NA
4:        2  player_1 venue A opponent B      1     10   NA   NA    NA     5    10
5:        1  player_1 venue A opponent A      1      5   NA   NA    NA    NA     5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to do something like this:

0. Set the data as data.table

```
setDT(data)
```

1. Create a small function that returns a list of vectors, showing the sequential last `n` points, given a vector as input

```
f <- function(x,n=3) lapply(n:1,\(i) x[i:(i+length(x)-1)])
```

2. Apply that function by the grouping vars of interest, remembering to order first. For example to get the prior points, just by player id, you can use `f()` like this:

```
data[
  order(-match_id),
  c("last3", "last2", "last1"):=f(points,3),
  by=player_id][]
```

3. If you want to group by venue and opponent as well, do this:

```
data[
  order(-match_id),
  c("last3", "last2", "last1"):=f(points,3),
  by=.(player_id, venue,opponent)][]
```

Output (by player_id):

```
    match_id player_id   venue   opponent points last3 last2 last1
      <char>    <char>  <char>     <char>  <num> <num> <num> <num>
 1:  match_1  player_1 venue A opponent A      5    NA    NA     5
 2:  match_1  player_2 venue A opponent A     10    NA    NA    10
 3:  match_1  player_3 venue A opponent A     15    NA    NA    15
 4:  match_2  player_1 venue B opponent B      1    NA     5     1
 5:  match_2  player_2 venue B opponent B      2    NA    10     2
 6:  match_2  player_3 venue B opponent B      3    NA    15     3
 7:  match_3  player_1 venue C opponent C      5     5     1     5
 8:  match_3  player_2 venue C opponent C      7    10     2     7
 9:  match_3  player_3 venue C opponent C      9    15     3     9
10:  match_4  player_1 venue C opponent C     11     1     5    11
11:  match_4  player_2 venue C opponent C      2     2     7     2
12:  match_4  player_3 venue C opponent C      6     3     9     6
```

If you want the combined column, you can do this, assuming that you assign the result of the above to `r1`

```
r1[, combined:=paste(last3,last2,last1,sep = ","), by=1:nrow(r1)][]
```

Output:

```
    match_id player_id   venue   opponent points last3 last2 last1 combined
      <char>    <char>  <char>     <char>  <num> <num> <num> <num>   <char>
 1:  match_1  player_1 venue A opponent A      5    NA    NA     5  NA,NA,5
 2:  match_1  player_2 venue A opponent A     10    NA    NA    10 NA,NA,10
 3:  match_1  player_3 venue A opponent A     15    NA    NA    15 NA,NA,15
 4:  match_2  player_1 venue B opponent B      1    NA     5     1   NA,5,1
 5:  match_2  player_2 venue B opponent B      2    NA    10     2  NA,10,2
 6:  match_2  player_3 venue B opponent B      3    NA    15     3  NA,15,3
 7:  match_3  player_1 venue C opponent C      5     5     1     5    5,1,5
 8:  match_3  player_2 venue C opponent C      7    10     2     7   10,2,7
 9:  match_3  player_3 venue C opponent C      9    15     3     9   15,3,9
10:  match_4  player_1 venue C opponent C     11     1     5    11   1,5,11
11:  match_4  player_2 venue C opponent C      2     2     7     2    2,7,2
12:  match_4  player_3 venue C opponent C      6     3     9     6    3,9,6
```

Here is the minimal set of code required:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(data)

f <- function(x,n=3) lapply(n:1,\(i) x[i:(i+length(x)-1)])

data[order(-match_id),c("last3", "last2", "last1"):=f(points,3),by=player_id]
data[, combined:=paste(last3,last2,last1,sep = ","), by=1:nrow(data)]
```

### Update -

The OP now wants to exclude some rows (skip over those rows) under certain conditions. If a mask can be passed to `f()`, which indicates which rows to include, then, we can adjust `f()` like this:

```
f <- function(x,n=3,m=rep(TRUE,length(x))) {
  x[!m] <- NA
  lapply(n:1,function(i) x[i:(i+length(x)-1)])
}
```

This example uses the above adjusted version of `f()` to skip over rows where `game_x==0`

```
data[
  order(-match_id),
  c("last3", "last2", "last1"):=f(points,3,game_x==1),
  by=.(player_id)][order(player_id,-match_id)][]
```

### Another update!,

Now the OP wants to completely exclude `game_x=0` rows.

```
rbind(
  data[game_x==0], 
  data[game_x==1][
  order(-match_id),
  c("last5", "last4", "last3", "last2", "last1"):=f(points,5),
  by=.(player_id)][order(player_id,-match_id)],
  fill=TRUE
)
```

Output:

```
   match_id player_id   venue   opponent game_x points last5 last4 last3 last2 last1
      <num>    <char>  <char>     <char>  <num>  <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num>
1:        3  player_1 venue B opponent A      0     15    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
2:        5  player_1 venue B opponent C      0      2    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
3:        4  player_1 venue B opponent C      1      1    NA    NA     5    10     1
4:        2  player_1 venue A opponent B      1     10    NA    NA    NA     5    10
5:        1  player_1 venue A opponent A      1      5    NA    NA    NA    NA     5
```

Comment: thank you! However when I type in the function I get this error: `Error: unexpected input in "f <- function(x,n=3) lapply(n:1,\"` I checked and I typed it correctly.

Comment: do you have R < 4.1? if so, use `function(i)` within the `lapply()` instead of the shorthand `\(i)`

Comment: ah, that makes sense. Are you able to provide what the full function would be? Sorry, I am not great with functions. Actually I have R 4.0.2

Comment: `f <- function(x,n=3) lapply(n:1,function(i) x[i:(i+length(x)-1)])`

Comment: thank you, this appears to be working. I will report back if any issues.

Comment: this works, but when I use the combined function: `r1[, combined:=paste(last3,last2,last1,sep = ","), by=1:nrow(r1)][]` I get a very long warning message, not sure why? `Warning message:
In `[.data.table`(player3, , `:=`(last_3_games_combined, paste(last3games,  :
  Invalid .internal.selfref detected and fixed by taking a (shallow) copy of the data.table so that := can add this new column by reference. At an earlier point, this data.table has been copied by R (or was created manually using structure() or similar). Avoid names<- and attr<- which in R currently (and oddly) may copy the...`

Comment: this pops up now and then if you make copies of the data.table; I'd have to see the steps you took in term of assignment.. Try avoiding any assignment, because all the columns can be generated in-place / by reference, using `:=` (See my note at the bottom of solution)

Comment: ok thanks for the explanation. I have posted an update above with a different variable. Perhaps you might be able to shed some light on this challenge?

Comment: Do you want to ignore points in rows where game_x = 0?  Otherwise, I don't understand what you mean. Look at player_2. Points in matches 4,3,2,1 are 2,7,2,10.  The first of these form a group where game_x == 0.  Therefore, the last three games in the match_id = match_4 row should be 2,7,2.

Comment: Yes, sorry I should have been clearer. I want to ignore points in rows where game_x = 0. So essentially these are skipped over.

Comment: You could consider asking a new question.  I'll give it some though, on how to do this best..

Comment: ok many thanks. I will post a new question also.

Comment: I think I just figured it out. see solution

Comment: that looks good! One last question - is there a way to skip over the `NA's` and just provide the last 3? It is hard to explain with the small sample above, but let me know if you would like me to provide a more detailed sample?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by skip the NAs. Perhaps you mean exclude rows where game_x==0, and reestimate?.. If that is the case, you can probably just do `data[game_x==1][
  order(-match_id),
  c("last3", "last2", "last1"):=f(points,3),
  by=.(player_id)]`

Comment: this appears to provide the same outcome. I have updated my OP above and explained further, perhaps you could see where I am going wrong?

Comment: @Michael See once again my edit.  I don't think its advised to continue adding questions, building one on top of another... Perhaps you can think about separate questions.. I've added a bunch of solutions to this series of questions, but none have been indicated as helpful.  Perhaps a new question will get you better answers, if these aren't working for you?

Comment: @ langtang thanks for the advice. You have been most helpful and I do appreciate it. I am still new to this and still learning. I did not know about marking the comments as useful, but I do now. I have done this and also marked your answer as useful and accepted it.